# Should I omit the subject immediate after a conjunction?

Tags: grammar

Consider the following

> A/an and the are articles. They are a type of determiner **and they go** before a noun.
>
> A/an and the are articles. They are a type of determiner **and go** before a noun.

The former comes from [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/a-an-and-the), which means it is definitely grammatically correct. How about the latter? Should I omit the subject immediate after a conjunction, which is, "they" here?

Why would I want to use the second one? Because it is more concise.

Comment: If you are asking for help, please write a question at the end stating what your problem is and what we can do to help you.

Comment: I cannot find a problem with either of the two.

Comment: Both seem correct and unambiguous.